# Using the word 'come' to mean 'when it comes'

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage

I am currently playing the game Max Payne 3 and I came across an interesting formulation:

> *I hope Fabiana will not be served to the fishes come feeding time*.

Is this normal in American English?

Comment: It's not American English, it's just English. And it's been around a long time. Cf. Ralph Vaughan Williams "English Folk Song Suite" which includes a song called ["Seventeen Come Sunday"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Folk_Song_Suite#1._March:_Seventeen_Come_Sunday), written almost 100 years ago.

Comment: *"Come rain, come shine, come feeding time"*. ["Come the revolution, you will be first up against the wall"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22come+the+revolution+you+will%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: There's also the American English idiom "come hell or high water", meaning "no matter what happens".

Answer (score 4):

This usage is not mentioned (at least as prepositional) in many of the online dictionaries. However, Google Dictionary includes it:

> **come**  preposition [informal]
>
> 1. when a specified time is reached or event happens. "I don't think that they'll be far away from honors come the new season"

It almost certainly derives from the common verb, with deletion (perhaps of 'when') and re-ordering. As this dictionary says, it wouldn't be used in a very formal register, though I wouldn't restrict it to informal ones. It does have a 'chatty' feel about it to my British ears.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it is not particularly common but yes, it is correct. Specifically, this is the meaning 2c(2) from the online [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come):

> c (2) :  take place —used in the subjunctive with inverted subject and verb to express the particular time or occasion <*come spring the days will be longer>*

It is not often used in day-to-day speech but you can still find it as you saw.

Comment: I'm not sure you can call it the subjunctive anymore. It's an idiom which originated in the subjunctive use, but this usage of the subjunctive has died in English, and I believe the meaning of the idiom has drifted away from the original meaning of the subjunctive.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm not sure either but that's what the MW states. I'm just quoting it.